# V4L2: Set Control Value without executing callbacks

Tags: linux-kernel, v4l2

I have a system with lots of custom controls via V4L2 (exposure, gain, etc).. However, I need the ability for some of these controls (like a regularly repeated initialization sequence) to reset the current values of these without executing the s_ctrl callback.

I've noticed that sending an ioctl to set a value more than once to the same value, only results in a single actual call to the s_ctrl.  However, I have some interconnected parameters that change these "under the covers" so I need to update the values so that a future value will be sent.

An example:

- Disable autogain
- Set gain to 100
- Turn on autogain
- gain moves around
- Turn off autogain
- Set gain to 100 <-- This one never happens, because it thinks the gain is still at 100 from before.

Comment: And yes, I tried setting the `->val` of the `v4l2_ctrl` entry.. It doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it...

You can directly set the `->cur.val` property of the `v4l2_ctrl` entries to do this.